# How do you use the values of a dataframe as a variable in a function to make a different column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a dataframe which i want to use as the values in it as the "x" in the function`0.00459652*np.exp(4.5*x)+0.000984312`
here is my code

```
df=pd.read_csv('F:/Data32.csv')
df2=df['Temperature']
x=df2.values.tolist()
test=df2.apply(0.00459652*np.exp(4.5*x)+0.000984312)
test
```

I keep getting the error
    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the function `0.00459652*np.exp(4.5*x)+0.000984312` to each value in the `Temperature` column, just put that column at the `x` location:

```
test = 0.00459652*np.exp(4.5*df['Temperature'])+0.000984312
```

The reason why you get that error is that `x` is a python list, which cannot be multiplied by a floating number (4.5 in this case). But `df['Temperature']` can (it's a pandas.Series)

Also, `0.00459652*np.exp(4.5*x)+0.000984312` is not a python function. You need `lambda x : 0.00459652*np.exp(4.5*x)+0.000984312`